# Add Value Labels in R

Tags: label

I would like to add value labels to a numeric variable I created.

In SPSS, this would be as simple as:

VALUE LABELS variable 1 'Unfavorable' 2 'Favorable'.

Can anyone provide a simple straight forward translation of that code in R?  Preferably without having to load more packages.

I have looked everywhere and cannot find any understandable examples.